# SharedPreferences, Singleton Class - What should you use for calling, editing, saving and recalling two integer values

Tags: java, android, singleton, sharedpreferences

My app will carry two scores the entire time, calling them, adding to them, saving them, and later calling them back again for other functions and editing. What is the best method for this? These will be the only numbers needed throughout the app.

All I am looking for is the most efficient option I should implement. And if possible a simple example of making, editing, saving and recalling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**You can use **SharedPreferences** To save Scores When you will call getFirstScore() first Time it will return 0 as the variable is not yet created and then you can call setFirstScore() to save it.

```
public class ScoreDatabase{
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public ScoreDatabase(Context context){
   this.context=context;
   pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   editor = pref.edit();

}

public int getFirstScore() {
    return pref.getInt("FIRST_SCORE", 0);
}

public int getSecondScore() {
    return pref.getInt("SECOND_SCORE", 0);
}

public void setFirstScore(int score) {
    editor.putInt("FIRST_SCORE", score);
    editor.commit();
}

public void setSecondScore(int score) {
    editor.putInt("SECOND_SCORE", score);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Now make instance of this class and use anywhere you want just pass getApplicationContext() in the constructor

```
//In your MainActivity class
ScoreDatabase scoreDatabase=new ScoreDatabase(getApplicationContext());
//call set function when you want to set score
scoreDatabase.setFirstScore(10);
scoreDatabase.setSecondScore(20);
//Call get function when you want to get score
int firstScore=scoreDatabase.getFirstScore();
int secondScore=scoreDatabase.getSecondScore();
```

Comment: When updating the score, this could be used on any activity? Or I would have to add something else to use it on another activity?

Comment: You can declare these two function inside a separate Class ScoreChanger and use this class object anywhere to get the value or set the value , If you didn't understand I can explain you with code

Comment: If you could break it down in code, that will help me understand it a lot better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **SharePreferences** because you are only need to store very small data.

Hint:

```
        synchronized void saveScores(final Context contex, final String scoreOneKey, final String scoreTwoKey, final Integer scoreOne, final Integer scoreTwo){

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user.score.key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

    final SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    preferencesEditor.putInt(scoreOneKey, scoreOne);

    preferencesEditor.putInt(scoreTwoKey, scoreTwo);

    preferencesEditor.commit();

}
```

Things to Note here are:

1. You are method must synchronized as multiple threads can access the game score.
2. Notice the sharedPreference access controls (MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_MUTI_PROCESS) that tells the OS that this sharedPreference is not accessible by other apps but at same time it is possible to access it from multiple process of your app ( if you can even encrypt the scores before saving them.)